# I'm not able to start jetty server

Tags: jersey, glassfish, java-17

I'm using java 17 (actually migrating from java 1.8). At the time of starting jetty server, I'm having exceptions similar to the following:
`javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-53d15034==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer@91e694b5{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=true,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STARTED}`.

In short, what I'm trying to start is:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server().start();
```

`org.glassfish.jersey` version is `2.27`
`org.eclipse.jetty` version is `9.4.44.v20210927`

Any idea what might be going wrong or misconfigured?

Comment: Have you checked if these versions are compatible?

Comment: Can you recommend some easier way to compare the compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was using a mismatching jersey version.
When I switched to `org.glassfish.jersey` version `2.34` the servlet started successfully.